# no function or associated item named `from_str` found for type `hyper::mime::Mime`

Tags: rust

I'm using Hyper 0.11 which re-exports the crate "mime". I'm trying to create a MIME type from a string:

```
extern crate hyper;

fn main() {
    let test1 = hyper::mime::Mime::from_str("text/html+xml").unwrap();
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_str` found for type `hyper::<unnamed>::Mime` in the current scope
```

Why is this error, what's the cause? How to fix it?

Comment: New error, new question.  What makes you think `Header` is implemented for `Mime`? Not listed here: https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.17/hyper/header/trait.Header.html - perhaps you want the `ContentType` header, which has a `Mime` field.

Answer (score 9):

You get this error because, sure enough, there is no `from_str` method defined on [`Mime`](https://docs.rs/mime/0.3.5/mime/struct.Mime.html). In order to resolve a name like `Mime::from_str`, `from_str` has to be either an inherent method of `Mime` (not part of a trait), or part of a trait that is in scope in the place where it's used. `FromStr` isn't in scope, so you get an error -- although the error message goes so far as to tell you what's wrong and how to fix it:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_str` found for type `hyper::<unnamed>::Mime` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
3 | let test1 = hyper::mime::Mime::from_str("text/html+xml").unwrap();
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
  = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
          candidate #1: `use std::str::FromStr;`
```

However, in this *particular* case, it's more common to use `FromStr` not by calling `from_str` directly, but indirectly with the [`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) method on `str`, as [`FromStr`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) mentions.

```
let test1: hyper::mime::Mime = "text/html+xml".parse().unwrap();
```